# How to find date saved as string in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have in my collection the field **LAST_DATE_LIVE** field and the value is saved as **string** in format **DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss**, for example: **"06/12/2021 03:30:00"**.

I have a filter in my API, where it receives values as **"DD/MM/YYYY"** (Time is not allowed in the filter) and by range "DD/MM/YYYY-DD/MM/YYYY"). I'm using pipeline aggregation.

This is the part of the query:

```
            queryFilter = {
                $and: [
                    { 
                        $or: [
                            {
                                'LAST_DATE_LIVE': hasInterval ? { $gte: startDate, $lte: endDate } : { $regex: `^${startDate}` }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            };
```

The startDate has a value, as I mentioned in the DD/MM/YYYY format, the same thing for the endDate.

When I don't have a range, the query works wel, the problem is in the **range**.
Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Storing `"LAST_DATE_LIVE"` as a string with format `DD/MM/YYYY` is problematic.  Sorting, ordering, comparing, etc., is going to be more complex.  Consider storing dates as BSON Dates (best!), or at least as ISO8601 strings.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how you wish to handle the time component (e.g. is an end date of `2021-06-14` meaning midnight or 11:59:59) but in general this is easy to do if you work with real dates, not `DD/MM/YYYY` strings.

```js
sd = new ISODate('2021-06-13');
ed = new ISODate('2021-06-14');
c=db.foo.aggregate([
    {$match: {$expr:
          // The $dateFromString function is rather "long" so instead of 
          // calling it twice, use $let to set up a converted
          // value once and use it in the $and:
          {$let: {
                  vars: {'xd': {$dateFromString: {
                      dateString: '$LAST_DATE_LIVE',
                      format: '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S'}} },
                  in:  {$and:[ {$gte:['$$xd',sd]}, {$lte:['$$xd',ed]} ]}
              }}
     }}
]);
```